# Ruby on Rails 4 Unable to autoload constant via autoload paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would be very grateful to receive advice on resolving the error below.

config/application.rb

```
...
   config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/packages/"]
...
```

helpers/application.rb

```
...
def package_handler_by_name(name)
  "#{name}_package".classify.constantize.new    
end
...
```

controllers/packages_controller.rb

```
...
include ApplicationHelper
...
    def get_packages
      @package_handlers = {}
      @package_names = Dir.glob("#{::Rails.application.config.root}/app/packages/*.rb").map {
        |f| 
          name = File.basename(f).chomp("_package.rb")
          @package_handlers[name] = package_handler_by_name(name) **error**
          name
    }
    end
...
```

Error tracing back to line marked with **error**

```
Unable to autoload constant SubscriptionPackage, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/packages/subscription_package.rb to define it
```

Of course packages/subscription_package.rb exists (or else we'd receive an error on the preceding line).

Comment: Could you show us the contents of _subscription_package.rb_

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in **subscription_package.rb** which introduced a wrong class name.
Case closed, many thanks to Leito for pointing out.